# WindowsPhone 8 （A jump to another application ）FindPackagesForCurrentPublisher

Tags: windows-phone-8

```
string ProductId = "{23e1505b-9383-4ed4-9195-da23a3442820}";

IEnumerable<Package> app = Windows.Phone.Management.Deployment.InstallationManager.FindPackagesForCurrentPublisher();
            app.First().Launch(ProductId);
```

this another app

```
WMAppManifest.xml(App xmlns="" ProductID="{23e1505b-9383-4ed4-9195-da23a3442820}" 
Title="@TitleStrings\AppResLib.dll,-100" RuntimeType="Silverlight" Version="3.5.1.17" 
Genre="apps.normal" Author="Tencent WeChat Limited" Description="Wed Feb 20 17:37:10 2013, 
ChannelID 70" Publisher="Tencent WeChat Limited" IsBeta="false">)
```

When I trigger the event, it did not `Launch (ProductId)` I debugged, who can tell me. Did not run this step. How to jump to another application which used this method... thank you

Answer (score 0):

`Launch()` doesn't take the product ID of the app you want to launch. Instead, it takes a query string that will passed along to the app you're launching, usually with a page reference.

What's probably happening is that the first app in `app` is actually the current app--the one that's making the call. It doesn't make any sense for an app to launch itself from within the app, so nothing happens.

Instead of calling `First()`, you should instead filter `app` so you can select the one that has a matching product ID. Look into [Package.ID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.package.id.aspx) for details on how to do this.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt but why don't I specify an Id program to jump to the designated in the App, you can tell me something? This method can from one application to jump to the other to any third party applications.. Can you tell me the detail, in order to this problem, I have struggled for a week.. Please help me with my thanks

Comment: Generally you can't open any arbitrary other application on the phone.  The point of `FindPackagesForCurrentPublisher()` is to get other apps that you have published so that you can jump in between them if you want.  The list of apps returned by `FindPackagesForCurrentPublisher()` is the list of apps that you are allowed to jump to.  Each package in the list has an ID associated with it, so you don't need to pass it in when calling Launch.